# Monitor administrative shares access in Windows

Tags: windows, network-shares

In my company administrative shares (c$, d$, etc) are used by admins to deploy specific files to Windows employees' computers. Some privacy concerns have arisen since while this is necessary to deploy updates and configuration files, it gives admins access to ALL files on hard disks, and some users may have personal or confidential information not supposed to be accessed by IT.

That's why I wonder if is there any way to keep track of the administrative shares usage (the files being accessed, when they are accessed and the admin user accessing them), either from the domain controllers or from the users' computers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain Administrators can access anything they want. Generally without Auditing, you might never know.

You would need to enable (configure) Audit Policies on the Server and the Workstations. You do this in the Group Policy Editor for the server and needed machines

This would be for auditing going forward and not ever going backward in time.

It may be worth keeping secured files in a secured folder on the server (which is normally backed up) and not on any workstation. This is safer and will reduce your work.

[Enable Auditing](https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/windows-workstation-auditing-guide-configuring-audit-policies-manually.html#:%7E:text=Choose%20Computer%20Configuration%20%3E%20Policies%20%3E%20Windows,the%20policy%20and%20click%20OK.)

> Go to Start > Active Directory Users and Computers. Right-click the
> domain and select New > Group. In the New object - Group window that
> opens, type in "ADAuditPlusWS" as the Group name, check Group scope:
> Global and Group type: Security. Click OK. Right-click the newly
> created group, then select Properties > Members > Add. Add all
> configured workstations as a member of this group. Click OK.

> Using
> domain admin credentials, log in to any computer that has the Group
> Policy Management Console (GPMC) on it. Note: The GPMC will not be
> installed on workstations and/or enabled on member servers by default,
> so we recommend configuring audit policies on Windows domain
> controllers. Otherwise follow the steps in this page to install GPMC
> on your desired member server or workstation.
>
> Go to Start > Windows Administrative Tools > Group Policy Management.
> In the GPMC, select Domains and right-click the domain you want to
> configure Group Policy for. Select Create a GPO in this domain, and
> Link it here... In the New GPO window that opens, type in "_ADAuditPlusWSPolicy" and click OK. Select the GPO _ADAuditPlusWSPolicy. Under Security Filtering, select
> Authenticated Users. Click Remove. In the Group Policy Management
> window that opens, select OK. Select the _ADAuditPlusWSPolicy GPO. Under Security Filtering, click Add and
> choose the security group ADAuditPlusWS created previously. Click OK.